# Can not connect to MongoDB from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, nginx, php-mongodb

I have installed MongoDB PHP lib

[image: phpinfo screenshot]

but despite this I can't connect to MongoDB database

**Error of rockmonogo :**

```
To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. Here for installation documents on PHP.net.
```

**Error of phpmoadmin :**

```
PHP cannot access MongoDB, you need to install the Mongo extension for PHP.
```

**Error of Laravel with Jenssegers\Mongodb lib :**

```
Unsupported driver [mongodb]
```

Comment: can you put your code here, as to how are yo trying to connect to mongo via php

Comment: rockmongo and phpmoadmin are MongoDB administration tool package.

Comment: We need to see how you are trying to connect. Need some code to analyse what must be wrong

Comment: [Rockmongo](http://rockmongo.com)
**my config** :
`$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_name"] = "localhost";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "127.0.0.1";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_port"] = "27017";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_timeout"] = 0;
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_db"] = "MONGO_DATABASE";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_user"] = "MONGO_USERNAME";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = "MONGO_PASSWORD";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = true;`

Comment: i find this code : 
      'if (!class_exists("Mongo") && !class_exists("MongoClient")) {
 exit("To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. <a href=\"http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php\" target=\"_blank\">Here for installation documents on PHP.net.</a>");
}'

Comment: try {
 $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
}
catch(Exception $ex) { 
 throw $ex;
}

Comment: result : Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ../mongodb.php on line 4

Comment: It concludes that there are no packages to support php mongo connection in your system. Check Anthonys answer below to install the package

Comment: i put screenshot from phpinfo . this package is installed . but don't work

Comment: Run `php -i` from terminal and see if it outputs the same as your phpinfo() page.

Comment: yes they are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that it is in fact properly installed. The errors you're getting seem to indicate that your environment can't find the extension. I've compiled installation instructions for you.

## Unix-like Systems

1. Open a terminal emulator and run `wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`
2. Then start the installation of PECL with `php go-pear.phar`
3. Install the PHP MongoDB extension `sudo pecl install mongodb`.
4. Add `extension=mongodb.so` to the **php.ini** file.

## Mac OS X

1. Install homebrew by running `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` in a terminal.
2. Run `brew update`
3. Run `brew tap homebrew/php`
4. Install the extension according to your PHP version.

   - PHP 5.4: `brew install php54-mongodb`
   - PHP 5.5: `brew install php55-mongodb`
   - PHP 5.6: `brew install php56-mongodb`
   - PHP 7.0: `brew install php70-mongodb`

## Windows

1. Open your web browser to http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb
2. Open the latest version from the **DLL** link (with the Windows icon).
3. Choose the appropriate version from the DLL list. They are sorted by PHP version, system architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs 64-bit), and thread safety.
4. Extract the downloaded archive and place *php_mongodb.dll* in your PHP extensions directory.
5. Add `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to the **php.ini** file.

Comment: Is the correct version is installed? Have you added it to the correct php.ini file? Have you restarted your server?

Comment: mongodb version : 3.2.7 , php version : 5.6.25 , library version : 1.1.8.
yes , if no added to php.ini didn't show in phpinfo
restart php-fpm and nginx then restart my fedora
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Ok, so the library version is the latest, but your PHP version is 5.6. There are different types of the mongodb extension library and it's important you get the correct one. The one for php 7.0 and 5.5 will not work. So be sure it's the one for 5.6. Of course, choose the one for your architecture (x86 vs x64). And finally choose the Thread Safe version unless you're using it over FastCGI.

Comment: in [Mongodb Site](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) writed support php version 5.6

Comment: That website tells me nothing. What operating system are you using?

Comment: my operating system is Fedora 24

Answer (score 0):

For mac system, the homebrew php tap mechanism is deprecated and it won't work. You need to manually install it or you need to install Ampps which contains all the packages in built.

The following error might be thrown for the user with new version of the system

```
 Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
```